# JS - does NodeList.forEach asyc on my website?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I'm writing some JS for my webpage.

I have queried a list of divs using `document.querySelectorAll` then using `NodeList.forEach`
(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

However I would like to know will my code run sequencially - namely the callback in my `NodeList.forEach` pushes some items into an array.

Can I be certain that the next step will only happen once that forEach has iterated through each element?

```
  //Get all the selected tags
  selectedTags = document.querySelectorAll('[class*=lpSelectedTag]');
  selectedTagsArray = [];

  //Get the values attribute
  selectedTags.forEach(function(currentValue) { 
    selectedTagsArray.push(currentValue.attributes.value.value); 
  });

  //Then create some fancy string using selectedTagsArray
```

So at the last point where I make my 'fancy string' - would that line always occur after the forEach?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can I be certain that the next step will only happen once that forEach has iterated through each element?

Yes. `NodeList#forEach` is a synchronous operation.

---

Side note: You could use `Array.prototype.map`:

```
selectedTagsArray = Array.prototype.map.call(selectedTags, function(currentValue) { 
    return currentValue.attributes.value.value; 
});
```

or in ES2015+:

```
selectedTagsArray = Array.from(selectedTags).map(function(currentValue) { 
    return currentValue.attributes.value.value; 
});
```

or:

```
selectedTagsArray = [...selectedTags].map(function(currentValue) { 
    return currentValue.attributes.value.value; 
});
```

---

Side note 2: If you want the *current value* of an `input`, it's not an attribute; use the `value` property instead: `currentValue.value`, not `currentValue.attributes.value.value`.

Comment: Thanks - going forward how can I check that for myself - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach doesnt mention? Is it assumed with the callback?

Comment: @userMod2 - Unless something explicitly says it's asynchronous, you can generally assume it's synchronous.